# Dropdown lists and button appears to be disabled (not working) resizing the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a strange behavior with drop down lists and button in my layout.
I have just made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2zqqyzj1/1/) to illustrate how this looks like.

As you can see in the example, if you resize the browser the you can still open the lists or click on the `Filter` button which is ok.

When I do the same on my desktop, the first list will work properly, but the second and third list will not open as well the button in not clickable anymore.

I have spent the all day trying to fix this issue, unfortunately with no success at all.

Maybe someone of you guys have had the same issue or knows what is going on here?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In what size this happening?  I changed my browser size but did not see the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered issue like that before when wrapper elements were stretching over other elements via zindex and couldn't track it down until i gave each element a background color and could see how they were transforming in size as i adjusted the window size.

Comment: What you suggest has nothing to do with this. As you can clearly see in the fiddle demo, the elements are NOT overlapping each other when you resize the browser window.